# How to align a div with 'inline-block' property inside another 'div'?

Tags: html, css

How do I align the `.square`inside the `#about_container`?

They should all sit `10px` from the top of `#about_container`, with or without text.

```css
#about_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(146, 106, 106, 1);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="about_container">
  <div class="filler_space"></div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>Well here hfdasjkhfidi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="filler_space"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the `.square` class.

If you want the text to break when it reaches the end of the width, you can set `white-space: normal` on the `.square` class so that it doesn't inherit the `white-space: nowrap` rule from its parent.

```css
#about_container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(146, 106, 106, 1);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="about_container">
  <div class="filler_space"></div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>Meow mix delivers chicken and liver. Meow mix delivers chicken and liver.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="filler_space"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed...thank you Talmid! Also, why doesn't my text break when it reaches the end of the width?

Comment: I edited my post to include an answer to your text break question.